# Inserting data into SQL Server database with razor (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, razor

I'm having problems connecting my project to a database, I do not understand the reason, already full of various types, use of server 17, I get access to an application in an application, but the site is not working.

[imagem do erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XExHX.png)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SicConnectionString" 
         connectionString ="Data Source=ETID-012312\\ETID012312;User=sa;Password=admin2312;Initial Catalog=Sic_db;Integrated Security=True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

register.cshtml

```
@{
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Cadastro";

var fantasia = "";
var cnpj = "";
var cep = "";
var endereco = "";
var estado = "";
var cidade = "";
var bairro = "";
var celular = "";
var telefone = "";
var email = "";
var usuario = "";
var senha = "";
var csenha = "";
var error = false;
var resultado = "";

if (IsPost)
{
    var db = Database.OpenConnectionString("Data Source=;User=;Password=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True;");
    fantasia = Request.Form["fantasia_txv"];
    cnpj = Request.Form["cnpj_txv"];
    cep = Request.Form["cep_txv"];
    endereco = Request.Form["endereco_txv"];
    estado = Request.Form["estado_txv"];
    cidade = Request.Form["cidade_txv"];
    bairro = Request.Form["bairro_txv"];
    celular = Request.Form["celular_txv"];
    telefone = Request.Form["telefone_txv"];
    email = Request.Form["email_txv"];
    usuario = Request.Form["usuario_txv"];
    senha = Request.Form["senha_txv"];
    csenha = Request.Form["csenha_txv"];

    // Define the insert query. The values to assign to the
    // columns in the Product table are defined as parameters
    // with the VALUES keyword.

        var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.TempAcc (TA_fantasia, TA_cnpj, TA_cep, TA_endereco, TA_estado, TA_cidade, TA_bairro, TA_celular, TA_telefone, TA_email, TA_usuario, TA_senha)" +
            "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11)";
        db.Execute(insertQuery, fantasia, cnpj, cep, endereco, estado, cidade, bairro, celular, telefone, email, usuario, senha);
        // Display the page that lists products.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the "add image* toolbar button to upload your images. This puts them into Stack Overflow's space, which ensures that they stay available to accompany your question in the future. If you don't want to do that, then post the error information as text in your question instead.

Comment: I'm having problem reading [this](https://imgur.com/a/Jb0bG). Please help and poste the message as text with your question.

Comment: Yes, you can, just like thousands of others do each day.

Comment: I got it, it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Keyword not supported*" indicates the problem exist in your connection string in configuration file like this:

```
<add name="SicConnectionString" 
     connectionString ="Data Source=ETID-012312\\ETID012312;User=sa;Password=admin2312;Initial Catalog=Sic_db;Integrated Security=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The `User=sa` parameter is not supported in `SqlClient` connection, you need to use `User Id=sa` to mention user credentials:

```
<add name="SicConnectionString" 
     connectionString ="Data Source=ETID-012312\\ETID012312;User Id=sa;Password=admin2312;Initial Catalog=Sic_db;Integrated Security=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Also you need to modify `db` to match the connection string parameter given below:

```
var db = Database.OpenConnectionString("Data Source=;User ID=;Password=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True;");
```

You can check validity of the connection string as provided in [SQL Server Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Comment: The link you sent me made me understand that username and password do not need to be declared in a local instance and should be declared as you indicated if the instance is on a server, thank you.